# find a text from any column in csv using python

Tags: python, csv, full-text-search, string-matching

i am trying to search for a specific text in a csv file i am using any(iteratable) to iterate through all columns in csv for this but it returns of true whatever i search for.. here's my code...

```
input_text_frmwebsite =" five41-613-four731  "
input_text = input_text_frmwebsite.strip()    

with open('items2.csv', 'rt') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
            for line in reader:
                if any(input_text in col for col in line):
                    print "its in file"
                else:
                    print "not in file"
```

and my CSV file looks like this
[image]

Comment: Please provide the input in text format instead of as an image.

Comment: if i won't put image it would be difficult to see my csv structure thats why i posted image...sorry about that

Comment: Why is your indentation so inconsistent? Please fix!

Comment: here it's a better version of the image...
[link] http://i.stack.imgur.com/H6yvW.png

Comment: If all you are trying to find out is if the text is in the file why bother parsing it with `csv.reader`?  Why not just `if input_text in f.read()`?  Also, since you appear to be using Python 2, you should open your csv file in mode `'rb'`.  To debug your issue, add this print statement `print input_text, line`.  Then you will see what is being matched.

Comment: @asav .. Are you looking for only one phone number or any phone no?

Comment: @user3570335....no it's just for test...i will be taking input from a html form for matching that input text to the text in csv.